# How to convert string formed by numpy.array2string back to array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a string of numpy array which is converted by using `numpy.array2string`

Now, I want back my numpy array.

Any suggestions for how I can achieve it?

My Code:

```py
img = Image.open('test.png')
array = np.array(img)
print(array.shape)
array_string = np.array2string(array, precision=2, separator=',',suppress_small=True)
```

P.S My array is a **3D** array not 1D and I am using `,` separators, not the default blank

Comment: Why can't you just use your original array?

Comment: `np.fromstring()` maybe?

Comment: I am trying to write encryption algo and that's why I need an array to string and then back again @YashKrishan

Comment: No, I tried but it didn't work @MarkSetchell

Comment: `np.fromstring()` is depricated, use `np.frombuffer()` instead

Comment: `array2string` like the regular `str` display of an array is not intended for reverse conversion.  It includes brackets, ellipsis, and omits the comma delimiter.  Making a string from `arr.tolist()` is better.  That can be turned back into a list with `eval`.  The list could also be formatted to/from `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I just tried this and it worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('2.jpg')

arr = np.array(img)

# get shape and type
array_shape = arr.shape
array_data_type = arr.dtype.name
# converting to string
array_string = arr.tostring()

# converting back to numpy array
new_arr = np.frombuffer(array_string, dtype=array_data_type).reshape(array_shape)
print(new_arr)
```

For converting numpy array to string, I used `arr.tostring()` instead of `arr.array2string()`. After that converting back to numpy array works with `np.frombuffer()`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'

Comment: buffer accepts byte but here we are providing string

Comment: Then maybe you can use `np.fromstring()` instead of `np.frombuffer`. But it may show Deprecation Warning

Comment: What's the output or error when you use `np.fromstring()` ?

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2330 into shape (11,10,4)

Comment: I updated my answer. Please take a look. For converting numpy array to string, I used `arr.tostring()` instead of `arr.array2string`. After that converting back to numpy array works fine. Just copy the whole code and run it. Hope my answer helps :)

Comment: `arr.tostring()` is deprecated now

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a hack, but may be the simplest solution.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[[1,2,3,4]]]) # create a 3D array
array_string = np.array2string(array, precision=2, separator=',', suppress_small=True)
print(array_string) #=> [[[1,2,3,4]]]

# Getting the array back to numpy
new_array = eval('np.array(' + array_string + ')')
```

Since the string representation of the array matches the argument we pass to build such array, using eval successfully creates the same array.

Probably is best if you enclose this in a `try` `except` in case the string format isn't valid.

Comment: Also, this method doesn't assume you have any knowledge about the array type and shape. This might be helpful if your intention is that the encryption should only hold the contents of the array and no other information about it.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.array2string()` gives output string as : `'[1, 2]'` so you need to remove the braces to get to the elements just separated by some separator.

Here is a small example to extract the list elements from the string by removing the braces and then using `np.fromstring()`. As you have used `','` as the separator when creating the string, I am using the same to delimit the string for conversion.

```
import numpy as np
x = '[1, 2]'
x = x.replace('[','')
x = x.replace(']','')
a = np.fromstring(x, dtype=int, sep=",")
print(a)

#Output: [1 2]
```

Comment: It's something like this

'[[[255,128,  0],\n \n  [  0,  0,255]],\n\n [[255,128,  0],\n  [255,128,  0],\n  [255,128,  0],\n  ...,\n  [  0,  0,255],\n  [  0,  0,255],\n  [  0,  0,255]]]'

Comment: In that case, is this the best representation of your data I mean, you can format it better at the time of generation to make a more generic list.

Comment: Parsing a 1d array representation is bad enough, doing the same with a multidimensional isn't worth the effort.  Choose a different string format.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def fromStringArrayToFloatArray(stringArray):
  array = [float(s) for s in stringArray[1:-1].split(' ')]
  return np.array(array)

x = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
y = np.array2string(x)
z = fromStringArrayToFloatArray(y)
x == z
```

You can use a list comprehension to split your array into different strings and then, convert them to float (or whatever)

Comment: unfortunately that won't work for nested (multi-dimensional) arrays.